# DynamoDB Local Secondary Index pro/cons?

Tags: database-design, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm utilizing DynamoDB and EMR to create an application that tracks user statistics for a consumer product. I want to be able to do things like find all accounts that had over 20 comments every day for the last week. My current idea is to use account id as the hash key and time as my range key- I'll flatten the times so they conform to day/hour/week intervals and aggregate event data in one item. I plan on being able to track multiple events. Would using local secondary indicies on events be a good idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called *local*  secondary indices because they still only work within the context of the primary key. The query `find all accounts` means that you will still require a full table scan.

Were you thinking of using number of comments as the LSI?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea- The query I imagine myself making is something like: find all accounts with under 20 uploads on any given day between one week ago and today. I was hoping my case would be similar to the one described here: http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2013/04/dynamdb-local-secondary-indices.html but from what you're saying it seems like thats not the case. Thinking about it more, I don't think it'll be necessary for my case- that's what I'll use EMR for. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: His example queries still all query by HashKey. For example: “Show me the last 10 games played by John” and  “Show me John’s all-time top 5 scores.”. Your equivalent is "Show me the last 10 games played by anybody" or "Show me all-time top 5 scores across all players."